# Property width is not working when putting in dropdown-content

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am making a dropdown menu, but there is a problem that when I am adding `width:15%` in the `dropdown-content` its not working but if I am adding it in `#dropdown` then it is working. So pls tell me that if I wanna put the width in dropdown-content then why is it not working?

```css
h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding-block: 1rem;
  }

  .dropbtn{
      position: relative;
      left: 17%;
  }

  #dropdown {
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f2f3a2;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    left: 0%;
    border-radius: 5%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(90, 216, 90);
  }
  
  .dropbtn:hover+.dropdown-content {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
        <div id="dropdown" class="animate__animated animate__rollIn">
            <h3 class="dropbtn">STRATEGY</h3>
            
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="Short Straddle with Divisor Based SL.html">Short Straddle with Divisor Based SL</a>
              <a href="short straddle sl.html">Short Straddle with Trailing SL</a>
              <a href="straddlesimple.html">09:20 Straddle (Simple)</a>
              <a href="straddle shift sl.html">09:20 Straddle (Shift SL to Cost)</a>
              <a href="straddle roll the pending.html">09:20 Straddle (Roll the Pending Leg)</a>
              <a href="index combo.html">Index Combo</a>
              <a href="index option buying.html">Index Option Buying</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    
            <h3 style="position: relative;right: 5%; color: white;" class="animate__animated animate__rollIn"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="https://eaccount.indiainfoline.com?ReferralEmpId=WIl3W6p+0CSxgb43zO5CDA==&IsZ20Scheme=PWFawC7VFMmiW4Oysu+Kwg==" target="blanc"> OPEN DEMAT ACCOUNT</a></h3>
            <h3 style="position: relative;right: 7%;" class="animate__animated animate__rollIn">AMIBROKER AFL</h3>
            <h3 class="animate__animated animate__rollIn" style="position: relative;right: 8.5%;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the dropdown-content has a fixed position, that's why you need to tell the browsers what is a width of parent element. The width of children takes a settled percentage value of parent. It means that if you set 15% for child element, then you need set to your parent some constant value, like width: 300px in order to inform the browsers to which element the value of the child relates.

Comment: Yeah but when I give #dropdown (Parent Element) width as 150px and .dropdown content 115% width than the dropdown list is going out as it can only expand to last letter which is 'Y' in this case.